# Remove some files but not all

Tags: rm

I have a directory with some files, especially `.tex` files and those created by `pdflatex`. I want to be able to give a name `name` and remove all the files called `name` except `name.tex`

I tried

```
rm name.* !(name.tex)
```

but it has removed every file in the directory (even those called name2)
I suppose I can create a function or something but if I don't have to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided bash's extended globbing is enabled (which it is in the default Ubuntu `~/.bashrc`), you can use `name.!(tex)` to match `name` followed by any dot extension except `.tex`

Ex. given

```
$ ls name*
name  name2  name.bar  name.foo  name.tex  name.txt
```

then

```
$ ls name.!(tex)
name.bar  name.foo  name.txt
```

To *remove* the matching files, replace `ls` by `rm` (or - safer - by `rm -i`).

Comment: What is the difference between `rm` and `rm -i` ?

Comment: The latter ask for confirmation before deleting the files.